# Syntax invalid?

Tags: python, syntax

For some reason I keep getting an invalid syntax error of my code on Debian. But when I run it on my mac nothing wrong happens and it runs smooth. Could you guys help me?

```
def read_config(cfg='~/instacron/config.txt'):
    """Read the config.

    Create a config file at `cfg` with the
    following information and structure:
        my_user_name
        my_difficult_password
    """
    import os.path
    _cfg = os.path.expanduser(cfg)
    try:
        with open(_cfg, 'r') as f:
            user, pw = [s.replace('\n', '') for s in f.readlines()]
    except Exception:
        import getpass
        print(f"\nReading config file `{cfg}` didn't work")
        user = input('Enter username and hit enter\n')
        pw = getpass.getpass('Enter password and hit enter\n')
        save_config = input(
            f"Save to config file `{cfg}` (y/N)? ").lower() == 'y'
        if save_config:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(_cfg), exist_ok=True)
            with open(_cfg, 'w') as f:
                f.write(f'{user}\n{pw}')
    return {'username': user, 'password': pw}`
```

```
 print(f"\nReading config file `{cfg}` didn't work")
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you could create this error with only one line (that was runnable/usable standing alone), a [mcve] would be just that one line -- not your whole function. See also "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 5):

f-strings (`f"{var}"`) were only added to Python in version 3.6; earlier versions do not accept them.  Your Debian and Mac are clearly running different versions of Python, only one of which is at least 3.6.